# Are you allowed to book two appointments for Schengen visa at German consulates in different countries?

Tags: schengen-visas, residency, consulates

I understand that booking multiple Schengen visa appointments at the same German consulate is discouraged and they even say that your appointments would be automatically canceled if you do so.

But, can you book two appointments in two different countries? Say, one in Country A in July and one in Country B in August?

I haven't seen any rules against it, but I would like to know if anyone here ever done that. What I'm worried is less about the visa being rejected and more about the appointments being automatically canceled by the system. The appointments are hard to get, so if they're canceled I have to make another one and there might not be enough time for that.

Here's a couple more details:
● Why two appointments? It's related to the requirement that you should apply for a Schengen visa in your place of residence. I reside in Country B, but my travel schedule won't allow me to apply in the city. The only feasible time window to apply for a visa is when I'm in my home country (Country A) where I will stay for about one month.

● Why not wait for the outcome of the application in your home country (Country A) first before booking for one in Country B? Because appointments in Country B are so quickly filled up. I want to ensure that I have an appointment the moment I'm back in the country (which would be about 2 weeks before my intended trip to Germany) in case the embassy in Country A refused to process the application. Obviously, if I get the visa in Country A I will cancel the appointment in Country B.

Comment: If you're not _resident_ in county A, then the consulate there should refuse to process your application.

Comment: Allowed: yes, but they will notice it, maybe after first appointment, and this would cause many questions, non of them in your advantage. And you are creating more work on consulates and delaying other applicants. Not very ethical (so it could be against your application). If it is important: block the date in you calendar (it is also part of professionalism).